# Adding 2 matrices using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

I can acheive it by passing `(c,a,b)` to `add_mat` function, where result of `a,b` is stored in `c` like,

`void add_mat(int c[][3], int a[][3], int b[][3], int m, int n)`

What should be the return type of `add_mat` if I want to construct the funtion in this way

`?? add_mat(int a[][3], int b[][3], int m, int n)`

Below is a sample code

```
#include<stdio.h>

void read_mat(int a[][3], int m, int n){
    //scan data
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("[%d][%d] : ",i,j);
            a[i][j]=i+j;
        }
    }   
}
int* add_mat(int a[][3], int b[][3], int m, int n){
    int c[3][3];
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(){
    int a[3][3];
    int m=2,n=2; //mxn of a matrix

    read_mat(a, m, n);

    //add
    int b[3][3];
    read_mat(b, m, n);
    int* c[3][3];
    c = add_mat(a,b,m,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Like passing or pointing the calculated value `c` inside `add_mat` function to variable in `main` function.

Comment: I suggest `int c[3][3]; add_mat(c, a, b, m, n);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, since the memory of the `c` matrix will be gone when the function terminates.

You need to dynamically allocate it with `malloc()`, in order for the memory not to be free'd, unless *you* call `free()`. I have some examples for that in [2D dynamic array (C)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/), if you want to take a look.

With your previous function, you would create the matrix `c` outside the function (in `main()`), that's why dynamic memory allocation was not required.

---

PS: You should compile with warnings enabled:

```
prog.c: In function 'add_mat':
prog.c:19:12: warning: returning 'int (*)[3]' from a function with incompatible return type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     return c;
            ^
prog.c:19:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:32:7: error: assignment to expression with array type
     c = add_mat(a,b,m,n);
       ^
prog.c:31:10: warning: variable 'c' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int* c[3][3];
          ^
```

---

Here is a working example, which is just for demonstrative purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_mat(int a[][2], int n, int m){
    //scan data
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            a[i][j] = i + j ;
        }
    }
}

int **get(int N, int M) /* Allocate the array */
{
    /* Check if allocation succeeded. (check for NULL pointer) */
    int i, **table;
    table = malloc(N*sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        table[i] = malloc( M*sizeof(int) );
    return table;
}

void print(int** p, int N, int M) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < M ; j++)
            printf("array[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, p[i][j]);
}

void free2Darray(int** p, int N) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}

int** add_mat(int a[][2], int b[][2], int m, int n){
    int** c = get(n, m);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(){

    int n = 2, m = 2; //nxm of a matrix
    int a[n][m];

    read_mat(a, n, m);

    //add
    int b[n][m];
    read_mat(b, n, m);
    int** c;
    c = add_mat(a, b, n, m);

    print(c, n, m);
    free2Darray(c ,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
array[0][0] = 0
array[0][1] = 2
array[1][0] = 2
array[1][1] = 4
```

PPS: If you really want to use static arrays, then I recommend using `int c[3][3]; add_mat(c, a, b, m, n);`

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes, the pointers ...

In C, locally declared arrays usually are allocated on the stack (not on the heap) which means they are not valid outside the respective scope.

In other words, in your function `add_mat()`, `c` technically can be returned, but the address it points to will only contain meaningful matrix data as long as the function is executed.

After having returned from the function, the return value of the function is a pointer which still contains (points to) the *address* where the matrix was stored *during execution of the function*, but the *contents of that location*, i.e. the matrix data, can contain arbitrary garbage now.

So what you are doing is technically possible (i.e. throws no compile errors), but is definitely not what you want.

Secondly, your line `int* c[3][3];` probably is not what you intend it to be. You are declaring `c` to be a two-dimensional array (matrix) of *pointer to int* here. This is not correct since you want to process `int` values, but not *pointers* to `int` values (which are addresses).

To solve both problems, just write `int c[3][3];` instead of `int* c[3][3];` and change your `add_mat()` function as follows:

```
void add_mat(int a[][3], int b[][3], int c[][3], int m, int n){

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Then call that function like that:

```
add_mat(a,b,c,m,n);
```

Comment: that is why I was passing `c,a,b` to function .. nice explanation for knowing whats happening inside the hood .. @gsamaras answered as per my use case.

Comment: Thanks. If my explanation has been useful to you, then why not upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your code `add_mat` returns the pointer to the variable which lives while the function executes only. You can accomplish your goal with dynamically allocated matrix.

In C it is common to pass a dynamically allocated matrix via pointer to pointers to the rows of matrix as a first parameter:

```
void foo(int** matrix, size_t m, size_t n);
```

Here `matrix` is a pointer to the array of pointers. Every pointer in this array points to the row of matrix. So, `matrix[0]` points to the array containing the first row of matrix.

And it is common to use `size_t` type for any sizes of arrays.

If you need create matrix dynamically, be careful with memory. Every dynamically allocated block should be released. Otherwise you will get memory leaks, that may cause the program crash. Therefore, when you allocate rows of matrix, you should check if allocation of current row was successfull. If not, you should release all previously allocated rows.

There is a working code for your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void free_mat(int** a, size_t m) {
    if (!a) {
        return;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        free(a[i]);
    }

    free(a);
}

int** create_mat(size_t m, size_t n) {
    int** rows = calloc(m, sizeof(int*));
    if (!rows) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        rows[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        if (!rows[i]) {
            free_mat(rows, m);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return rows;
}

void read_mat(int** a, size_t m, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", a[i] + j);
        }
    }
}

void print_mat(const int* const* a, size_t m, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            printf("[%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int** add_mat(const int* const* a, const int* const* b, size_t m, size_t n) {
    int** c = create_mat(m, n);
    if (c) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    size_t m = 3;
    size_t n = 3;

    int** a = create_mat(m, n);
    int** b = create_mat(m, n);

    if (!a || !b) {
        printf("error when allocating matrix\n");
    }
    else {
        read_mat(a, m, n);
        read_mat(b, m, n);

        int** c = add_mat(a, b, m, n);
        if (!c) {
            printf("error when allocating matrix\n");
        }
        else {
            print_mat(c, m, n);
            free_mat(c, m);
        }
    }

    free_mat(a, m);
    free_mat(b, m);

    return 0;
}
```

But you would be more flexible, if `add_mat` didn't create a new matrix.
It is common to pass a pointer to the result matrix as a function parameter:

```
void add_mat(int** c, const int* const* a, const int* const* b, size_t m, size_t n);
```